# Category table with cat_ID's that match cat_subcat and include nulls

Tags: mysql, database

cat_ID | cat_Name | Cat_SubCat
1  | cameras | 17
2  | intercoms | 17
3  | televisions  | 20
4  | kitchen appliances |19
5  | speakers |20
6  | smart thermostat | 19
7  | smart outlets | 18
8  | robotic lawn mowers | 17
9  | smartphones | 21
11 | smart vaccums | 19
12 | smartwatches | 21
13 | smart locks | 17 
14 | smart doorbell | 17
15 | smart light switches | 18
17 | Security/Outdoors | NULL
18 | Lamps & Lights | NULL
19 | Household | NULL
20 | Entertainment | NULL
21 | Wearables | NULL
 
So I have a table called Category with columns named: cat_ID; cat_Name; and cat_SubCat; I have tried to get all of the category rows with null (heading) to print other rows and there associated cat_ID (subcategories under the heading)

[image: desired outcome]

cat_ID | cat_Name | Cat_SubCat
**17  |    Security/Outdoors    | Null**
1   | Cameras   | 17
2   | Intercoms | 17
9   |Robotic Lawn Mowers    | 17
13  | Smart Locks | 17
14  | Smart Doorbell |  17
**18    | Lamps & Lights |  Null**

7   | Smart Outlets |   18
15  | Smart Switches |  18
**19    | HouseHold |   Null**

4   | Kitchen Appliances |  19
6   | Smart Thermostat |    19
11  | Smart Vaccums |   19
**20    | Entertainment |   Null**

3   | Television |  20
5   | Speakers |    20
**21    | Wearables |   Null**

10  | Smart Phone | 21
12  | Smart Watches |   21

Comment: Can't see pictures (blind). If possible, providing the text would be good, otherwise someone else will have to answer this one.

Comment: tried to make a little better

Comment: Thanks. OK, so, I assume subcat has another table. You want subcat in main table to be int(length) with default NULL. Then create a foreign key type index and point it to the primary key of the subcat table (must be same type!!)

Comment: If that~ what you want, I'll write a sample code in an answer.

Comment: Everything is all in one table

Comment: Hm. Okay, what exactly is your problem, then?

Comment: having trouble writing code for the desired effect

Comment: looks like you want an order by subcat ASC... and you need a second parameter to place the NULL values correctly... maybe group by, though that'll put all things in one group into the same cell.

Comment: Since your hierarchy is only one deep then you can just do `ORDER BY COALESCE(cat_id, cat_subcat) ASC` on your existing SQL. If your hierarchy is more than one deep then you will need to do a recursive CTE to establish the order in a new column and sort by that.

Comment: @JNevill Put that in an answer, I wanna upvote. ;-)

Comment: @TimB done! I hope it does the trick though. I feel like there is more than one level here and it's going to get a *little* ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in this way

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b06d92/19)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`cat_ID` int, `cat_Name` varchar(20), `Cat_SubCat` varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`cat_ID`, `cat_Name`, `Cat_SubCat`)
VALUES
    (1, 'cameras', '17'),
    (2, 'intercoms', '17'),
    (3, 'televisions', '20'),
    (4, 'kitchen appliances', '19'),
    (5, 'speakers', '20'),
    (6, 'smart thermostat', '19'),
    (7, 'smart outlets', '18'),
    (8, 'robotic lawn mowers', '17'),
    (9, 'smartphones', '21'),
    (11, 'smart vaccums', '19'),
    (12, 'smartwatches', '21'),
    (13, 'smart locks', '17'),
    (14, 'smart doorbell', '17'),
    (15, 'smart light switches', '18'),
    (17, 'Security/Outdoors', NULL),
    (18, 'Lamps & Lights', NULL),
    (19, 'Household', NULL),
    (20, 'Entertainment', NULL),
    (21, 'Wearables', NULL)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select 
  t2.cat_ID,
  t2.cat_Name,
  t2.Cat_SubCat
from table1 t2
left join table1 t1
  on t2.Cat_SubCat = t1.cat_id
where t1.Cat_Subcat is null
order by Coalesce(t2.cat_subcat, t2.cat_Id-0.01)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b06d92/19/0)**:

```
| cat_ID |             cat_Name | Cat_SubCat |
|--------|----------------------|------------|
|     17 |    Security/Outdoors |     (null) |
|      1 |              cameras |         17 |
|     13 |          smart locks |         17 |
|     14 |       smart doorbell |         17 |
|      8 |  robotic lawn mowers |         17 |
|      2 |            intercoms |         17 |
|     18 |       Lamps & Lights |     (null) |
|     15 | smart light switches |         18 |
|      7 |        smart outlets |         18 |
|     19 |            Household |     (null) |
|     11 |        smart vaccums |         19 |
|      6 |     smart thermostat |         19 |
|      4 |   kitchen appliances |         19 |
|     20 |        Entertainment |     (null) |
|      5 |             speakers |         20 |
|      3 |          televisions |         20 |
|     21 |            Wearables |     (null) |
|      9 |          smartphones |         21 |
|     12 |         smartwatches |         21 |
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want to:

- Grab values that are null
- Grab the IDs for the null values, and if those ideas are subcategories, also grab those categories

Utilizing a subquery, this should accomplish your objective. We first grab all of the IDs for things that are null, then check to finally grab all values IF those null IDs are a subcategory, or the subcategory is null at all.

```
  SELECT 
    *
  FROM
    Category,
    (
      SELECT cat_ID,
      FROM Category
      WHERE Cat_SubCat is NULL
    ) tempTbl

  WHERE
    (Cat_SubCat is NULL)
    OR
    (tempTbl.cat_ID = Cat_SubCat)
```

Comment: (With) is throwing it off error(1 errors were found during analysis.

    Unrecognized statement type. (near "WITH" at position 0)

SQL query: Documentation

WITH ID AS ( SELECT cat_ID FROM Category WHERE Cat_SubCat is NULL ) SELECT * FROM Category WHERE (Cat_SubCat is NULL) OR (ID.cat_ID = Cat_SubCat)

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ID AS
(
  SELECT cat_ID
  FROM Category
  WHERE Cat_SubCat is NULL
)
SEL' at line 1) also not sure what it does

Answer (score 1):

Since your hierarchy is only one deep then you can just do:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(cat_id, cat_subcat) ASC
```

on your existing SQL.

If your hierarchy is more than one deep then you will need to do a recursive CTE to establish the order in a new column and sort by that.

Comment: so am I just doing a select * from category ORDER BY COALESCE(cat_id, cat_subcat) ASC because that didn't change anything. I thought about joins as well but I thought that I could get the data without using joins

Answer (score 0):

Simonare Thank You +1
select 
  t2.cat_ID,
  t2.cat_Name,
  t2.Cat_SubCat
from table1 t2
left join table1 t1
  on t2.Cat_SubCat = t1.cat_id
where t1.Cat_Subcat is null
order by Coalesce(t2.cat_subcat, t2.cat_Id-0.01)